# How to add custom Validation in antd form in react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am not able to figure out how to add custom validation in **antd** form in react. Validator function will work or not. Please suggest a suitable approach.

```
<Form.Item
  label="Name"
  name="name"
  rules={[
    {
      required: true,
      message: 'The name is required.',
    },
    {
      pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,
      message: 'Name can only include letters and numbers.',
    },
  ]}
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

Comment: Refer to the `validator` property from the [Rule API](https://ant.design/components/form/#Rule).

Answer (score 19):

Inside the rules array, you can define a custom validation by defining an async validator function.

```js
<Form>
  <Form.Item
    label="Name"
    name="name"
    rules={[
      {
        required: true,
        message: 'The name is required.',
      },
      {
        message: 'this is custom',
        validator: (_, value) => {
          if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value)) {
            return Promise.resolve();
          } else {
            return Promise.reject('Some message here');
          }
         }
       }
     ]}
  >
    <Input />
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: What if i get this from backend ?                                                                            
validation_rule = "[{\"rule\" : \"/^[a-zA-Z]{10}$/\", \"msg\" : \"Entered text length must be 10\"}]";

Comment: I have to validate the input and show the msg

Comment: you could test the regex with `/^[a-zA-Z]{10}$/.test(value)` and reject with `validation_rule.msg`, i'll edit the answer

Comment: Although if you only want to test if the input passes a regex you can use the native `{ pattern, message } interface like you posted in the question

Answer (score 0):

Inside the rules array, you can define a custom validation by this way

```
<Form>
    <Form.Item
      label="Name"
      name="name"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: "The name is required.",
        },
        ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
          validator(_, value) {
            if (regex.test(value)) {
              return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
              return Promise.reject(new Error("Some message here"));
            }
          },
        }),
      ]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
```

this by using getFieldValue you can access other field values too. it is really helpfull when your validation is dependant on other filed like password and confirm password.